# Trying to read from .txt file into an array list

Tags: java, netbeans, arraylist

Trying to read from .txt file into an array list to further import it into a GUI. The data in the .txt file is separated by "|" and the data consists of words and definitions. The GUI will display the definition and the user will input their answer in a jText Field which the program will then check the user answer against the actual word in the .txt file and record a score to be displayed at the end. We are extremely confused on what is wrong with the code because nothing is being displayed in the GUI. Thank you for any answers or suggestions.

```
package sat.vocab.practice;

/**
 *
 * @author Brandon Tavares
 * 
 */

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SATVocabPractice {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File("C:/Users/Brandon/Documents/NetBeansProjects/SAT Vocab Practice/src/sat/vocab/practice/Words.txt");
        try{
            ArrayList<String> lines = get_arraylist_from_file(f);
            for(int x = 0; x < lines.size(); x++){
                System.out.println(lines.get(x));
            }
            System.out.println("Reading");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    public static ArrayList<String> get_arraylist_from_file(File f) 
        throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner s;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        s = new Scanner(f);
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(s.next());
            list.add(s.next());
        }
        s.close();
        return list;
    }
}
```

Here is the GUI code.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package sat.vocab.practice;

/**
 *
 * @author Brandon
 */
public class MainView extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form MainView
     */
    public MainView() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        defintionHeader = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        definitionLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jToggleButton1 = new javax.swing.JToggleButton();
        score = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 255, 204));
        setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1920, 1080));

        defintionHeader.setText("Definition:");

        definitionLabel.setText("Definition Here");

        jLabel1.setText("Your Answer:");

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");

        jToggleButton1.setText("Submit Answer");

        score.setText("0");

        jLabel3.setText("Score:");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(63, 63, 63)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(score))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(defintionHeader)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(definitionLabel))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jToggleButton1)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 132, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addContainerGap(130, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(72, 72, 72)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(defintionHeader)
                    .addComponent(definitionLabel))
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                .addComponent(jToggleButton1)
                .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(score))
                .addContainerGap(45, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainView().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel definitionLabel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel defintionHeader;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JToggleButton jToggleButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel score;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: You are simply reading the lines, but not considering token '|' in the line. Can you please put your GUI code and and how you are sending the parsed data there?

Comment: I have added the GUI code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has exception. Try this.

```
   public static ArrayList<String> get_arraylist_from_file(File f) 
    throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner s;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    s = new Scanner(f);
    while (s.hasNext()) {
String temp=s.next();
        System.out.println(temp);
        list.add(temp);
    }
    s.close();
    return list;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the whole text file into a StringBuilder object using append method then turn the StringBuilder into an object array splitting on the "|" then loop through the object array and add each part of the object array to the array list.